# Why does a null date cause crosstab function to fail?

Tags: postgresql

I have discovered a strange behavior in postgres's crosstab function that I cannot explain, but hope someone else may...

The version of the crosstabs function I'm using requires first building a preliminary table.

This SQL successfully creates the preliminary table:

```
SELECT 
    ST.studyabrv||' '||S.labid||' '||S.subjectid||' '||S.box::varchar||' '||S.well AS "rowname",
    M.marker AS "bucket", 
    G.allele1||' '||G.allele2 AS "bucket_value" 
INTO TABLE ct 
FROM 
    geno.gmarkers M, 
    geno.genotypes G, 
    geno.gsamples S, 
    geno.guploads U, 
    geno.gibg_studies ST 
WHERE 
    G.markers_id=M.id 
    AND G.gsamples_id=S.id 
    AND S.guploads_id=U.id 
    AND U.ibg_study_id=ST.id 
    AND ( M.id=5 OR M.id=6 OR M.id=2 OR M.id=4 OR M.id=3) 
    AND ( S.labid='CL100001' OR S.labid='CL100002' OR S.labid='CL100003' OR S.labid='CL100004' OR S.labid='CL100005' OR S.labid='CL100006' OR S.labid='CL100007' OR S.labid='CL100008' OR S.labid='CL100009' OR S.labid='CL100010' OR S.labid='CL100011' OR S.labid='CL100012' OR S.labid='CL100013' OR S.labid='CL100014' OR S.labid='CL100015') 
ORDER BY box,well;
```

Which produces output like:

```
         rowname          |  bucket   | bucket_value 
--------------------------+-----------+--------------
 LTS CL100001 10011 1 A01 | 5HTTLPR-T | S La
 LTS CL100001 10011 1 A01 | 5HTTLPR-D | 14 16
 LTS CL100001 10011 1 A01 | DAT1      | 440 480
 LTS CL100001 10011 1 A01 | DRD4      | 475 475
 LTS CL100001 10011 1 A01 | Caspi     | 351 351
 LTS CL100009 10420 1 A02 | Caspi     |  
 LTS CL100009 10420 1 A02 | 5HTTLPR-T | La Lg
 LTS CL100009 10420 1 A02 | 5HTTLPR-D | 16 16
 LTS CL100009 10420 1 A02 | DAT1      | 440 480
 LTS CL100009 10420 1 A02 | DRD4      | 475 475
...
```

However, if I attempt to include a date column, which are all null, as in:

```
SELECT 
    ST.studyabrv||' '||S.labid||' '||S.subjectid||' '||S.box::varchar||' '||S.well||' '||G.run_date::text AS "rowname", 
    M.marker AS "bucket", 
    G.allele1||' '||G.allele2 AS "bucket_value" 
INTO TABLE ct 
FROM 
    geno.gmarkers M, 
    geno.genotypes G, 
    geno.gsamples S, 
    geno.guploads U, 
    geno.gibg_studies ST 
WHERE 
    G.markers_id=M.id 
    AND G.gsamples_id=S.id 
    AND S.guploads_id=U.id 
    AND U.ibg_study_id=ST.id 
    AND ( M.id=5 OR M.id=6 OR M.id=2 OR M.id=4 OR M.id=3) 
    AND ( S.labid='CL100001' OR S.labid='CL100002' OR S.labid='CL100003' OR S.labid='CL100004' OR S.labid='CL100005' OR S.labid='CL100006' OR S.labid='CL100007' OR S.labid='CL100008' OR S.labid='CL100009' OR S.labid='CL100010' OR S.labid='CL100011' OR S.labid='CL100012' OR S.labid='CL100013' OR S.labid='CL100014' OR S.labid='CL100015') 
ORDER BY box,well;
```

This produces the output:

```
 rowname |  bucket   | bucket_value 
---------+-----------+--------------
         | 5HTTLPR-T | S La
         | 5HTTLPR-D | 14 16
         | DAT1      | 440 480
         | DRD4      | 475 475
         | Caspi     | 351 351
         | Caspi     |  
         | 5HTTLPR-T | La Lg
         | 5HTTLPR-D | 16 16
```

As you can see, adding the run_date column to the end of the "rowname" composite column renders the entire composite blank...which is crazy. 
If I populate run_date with dummy data, it will show up....but if it is blank or null, this causes the "rowname" to go blank.

I cannot tell if this is a bug in postgres, but it is a bizarre result that I would like to resolve, if possible.

TIA,
rixter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think of `null` as an `unknown` value. `null` values are not numbers or strings so you can't opererate over them as if they were. So you should make sure you use some function that would return a non-null value, such as `coalesce()` that would return the first non-null parameter from left to right and force a *default* value as the right-most parameter.

Comment: Thanks! Will check out the coalesce function.

Comment: Welcome! Just don't raise postgresql guys a bug for this :P

Comment: This worked, using a dummy value agreed to by users: ||coalesce(G.run_date, '01/01/1900')::text

Answer (score 0):

```
|| coalesce(G.run_date, '')::text
```

Comment: Thanks! Will check out the coalesce function.